# Angular: how to reach local component var inside eventHandler function added with addEventListener

Tags: angular

Given the following:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hamburger-menu',
  templateUrl: './hamburger-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hamburger-menu.component.scss']
})

export class HamburgerMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  localString: string;

  constructor() {
    this.localString = 'hello';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handleDocumentClick);
  }

  handleDocumentClick($event: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log(this.localString);
    // 'this' is all of a sudden not the component anymore.
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleDocumentClick);
  }
}
```

Why is the component `this` not propagated inside the EventHandler function? How can I reach `this.localString` inside `handleDocumentClick`?

Comment: How you tried re-creating this issue on another editor? Just a wild guess; have you tried re-starting your angular server? Sometimes it gets janky and shows faulty errors

Comment: `this.handleDocumentClick` -> `this.handleDocumentClick.bind(this)` to make it work. Keep in mind to have a proper reference and later release the proper function. [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @robert Thx that worked, But how would I now properly remove the eventListener? neither `document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutsideMenuEvent);` or `document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClickOutsideMenuEvent.bind(this))` work.

Comment: "The bind() method creates a new function" save that as a member variable `this.fn = this.handleDocumentClick.bind(this);` and release `document.removeEventListener('click', this.fn);` declare fn something like this: `fn: () => {};`

Comment: @robert It copies the function and 'binds' in the `this`, that makes sense. In Vue this is all not needed, just works as my initial try. And I've realized you can bind only a small piece of the component that you need, instead of the whole `this`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to help from @robert

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hamburger-menu',
  templateUrl: './hamburger-menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hamburger-menu.component.scss']
})

export class HamburgerMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  localString: string;
  clickEventHandler: null | (($event: MouseEvent) => void);

  constructor() {
    this.localString = 'hello';
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // store reference to 'bound' function
    this.clickEventHandler = this.handleDocumentClick.bind(this);
    // add it
    document.addEventListener('click', this.clickEventHandler);
    // and properly remove it again
    document.removeEventListener('click', this.clickEventHandler);
    this.clickEventHandler = null;
  }

  handleDocumentClick($event: MouseEvent): void {
    // now it works
    console.log('localString', this.localString);
    // and event is also present ofc
    console.log('$event', $event);
  }
}
```

You need to use Typescripts 'bind' function, to merge the orginal EventHandler function with the `this` from the component. You also need to store a reference to it, otherwise you can never remove it again.